# Sphinxsearch stops indexing

Tags: sphinx

After updating to version 5.6, I can't index the database, because indexing stops in the middle without any messages:

[image]

In this state, the process hangs and nothing happens

top says that process doing something, but not 100% process time:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try strace -p <indexer's pid> and if you index from mysql what does "show processlist" show in the mysql instance?

Comment: You can also use `--print-queries` to check the query indexer is trying to execute.